# How to get all buttons in my page from a controller javascript function(component, event, helper)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button, onclick, dom, javascript-controller

I know how to enable the clicked button.
Lets say I want to enable all buttons on the click of a button.

The button is in a Lightning component as:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="msg" type="String"/>

<p>What happened: [<ui:outputText value="{!v.msg}"/>]</p>

<div>
    <ui:button label="A"
        press="{!c.disableMe}"/>

    <ui:button label="B"
        press="{!c.disableMe}"/>

    <ui:button label="Enable them all!!!"
        press="{!c.myClearButtonClicked}"/>
</div>
```

In my js controller:

```
myClearButtonClicked: function(component, event, helper) {

    var btnClicked = event.getSource();         // the button I clicked
    btnClicked.set("v.disabled",false);         // Enable the button
    component.set("v.msg", 'All buttons have been enabled'); // update message

    // I want to enable all buttons in the page instead of the one I clicked
    // How do I get a grip on those buttons from here ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `aura:id` to the `<ui:button />` component, then find the button by it.

**component:**

```
<ui:button aura:id="btn" label="A"
        press="{!c.disableMe}"/>

    <ui:button aura:id="btn" label="B"
        press="{!c.disableMe}"/>

    <ui:button aura:id="btn" label="Enable them all!!!"
        press="{!c.myClearButtonClicked}"/>
```

**controller method:**

```
var buttons = component.find("btn"); // return array if components with same 'aura:id' exist
if (buttons) {
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        console.log(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get all the ui:button's in the component, since they exist in the 'v.body' of the components super (every component has a super, if none defined it's merely aura:component):

```
var buttons = component.getSuper().find({ instancesOf : "ui:button" });
if (buttons) {
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].set("v.disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working!!!

Comment: the find(...) command returns nothing => buttons.length == 0

Comment: sorry, instancesOf only works if the v.body was used to set the elements / components inside of itself. Doing the aura:id way is better

Comment: found out that there's a fundamental understanding I was missing with v.body, it's actually on the super. Edited my reply to show how it could work